# Объясните что делает этот код

Tags: c++, struct

Не могу понять логику программы и задание в целом.

Дан следующий тип данных:

```
struct T 
{ 
   struct _T_ 
   { 
      int* a; 
   }* p1;

   float* a; 
   int* b; 

   struct _T 
   {
      int a; 
      int b; 
      double c; 
    }* p2; 

    int c; 
};
```

Само задание:

> Задайте каждому полю переменной `value` типа `Т` произвольное начальное
> значение в строке инициализации переменной

Объясните, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот код объявляет пользовательский тип данных `T`, в котором содержатся указатели на ещё 2 пользовательских типа данных `_T_` и `_T`.
Задание странное, с точки зрения использования имен вложенных структур - как будто специально старались запутать. Но на самом деле ничего страшного нет. Его можно только для наглядности переписать так:

```
struct _T_ 
   { 
      int* a; 
   };

struct _T 
   {
      int a; 
      int b; 
      double c; 
    };

struct T 
{ 
   _T_ *p1;

   float* a; 
   int* b; 

   _T *p2; 

   int c; 
};
```

Тогда задание значений будет так:

```
int main()
{
  T value{nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, 3};
}
```

Что равнозначно

```
int main()
{
  T value;
  value.p1 = nullptr;
  value.a = nullptr; 
  value.b = nullptr; 
  value.p2 = nullptr; 
  value.c = 3; 
}
```

Тут по-умолчанию указателям присваиваются `nullptr`. Если нужны конкретные значения, то нужно сначала создать конкретные объекты, а потом присвоить указателям их адреса:

```
int main()
{
  T::_T_ obj1;
  T::_T  obj2;
  int var1 = 1;
  float var2 = 2.0; 

  T value;
  value.p1 = &obj1;
  value.a = &var2; 
  value.b = &var1; 
  value.p2 = &obj2; 
  value.c = 3; 
}
```

Либо через динамическое выделение памяти

```
int main()
{
  T value;
  value.p1 = new(T::_T_);
  value.a = new(float);
  ...
}
```

Главное не забудьте всё, что выделяли через `new` удалить через `delete`.